# Solve $2\tan (x)\cos (x)=\tan (x)$, algebraically where $0 \leq x < 2\pi$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

please help me correct if anything is wrong.. or even if i'am right

---

> Solve $\quad 2\tan x\cos x=\tan x,$ algebraically where $0≤x<2π$

$$2\tan(x) \cos (x) - \tan (x) = 0$$

$$\tan (x)(2\cos (x) - 1) = 0$$

$$\text{So, either}\;\;\tan (x) = 0 \Longrightarrow x \in \{0, π,  2π\} $$

$$\text{Or}\;\;2\cos(x)-1 = 0, \cos (x) = 1/2 \implies x \in \{-π/3, π/3\}$$

$$\text{Solutions}\;\;: x \in \{0, \pi/3, -\pi/3, \pi, 2\pi\}$$

> 2) Solve $2\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)-1=0$ where $0≤x<2π$

$$2\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)-1=0$$

$$\iff(2\sin(x)+1)(\sin(x)-1) = 0$$

Thus, either $\;2\sin(x) +1 = 0 \iff \sin x = -1/2 \implies x = -π/6, x = 7π/6$

or $\;\sin(x)-1 = 0 \iff \sin x = 1 \implies  x = π/2$

$$\text{Solutions}\;\;x\in \{-π/6,  π/2, 7π/6\}$$

Comment: note if someone could help me clean the solution aswell :) mine look a little rough

Comment: Use `$ $` to enclose your equations. Use \sin, \cos, \tan \pi etc. This will greatly improve your question.

Comment: does my answer seem correct? if someone could help me

Comment: You were asked to find the solutions in the interval $0\le x\lt 2\pi$. A number of times, you give negative solutions. These do not satisfy the required condition. So for example you need to replace $-\pi/3$ in the first answer by $5\pi/3$. Similar corrections are needed elsewhere.

Comment: It would be better if you know how to use $\LaTeX$.  This way, we are able to read the equations clearly!

Comment: if $AB = 0$ then $A=0$ _or_ $B=0$, not "ALSO" as you have written. What you should do in a case like this is first explicitly consider one case "suppose $\tan(x)=0$, then...", which will give you some solutions, and then consider the other case, "now suppose $2cos(x)-1=0$..., which will give additional solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost!

You might want to give your first answer as inclusive of both possible sets of solutions - the solutions being those satisfying $\tan x = 0$ and/or satisfying $\cos x = 1/2$ - rather than as two answers.

Oops, just noted that you include $x = 2\pi$ as a solution to $\;\tan x = 0$, and it seems as though your domain for $x$ is written as $0\leq x \lt 2\pi$. If that's the correct domain for $x$, then omit $x = 2\pi$ as a solution to $(1)$.

And so you'll also need to omit $x = -\pi/3$, and instead include $x = 5 \pi/3$ as solutions to $\cos x = 1/2, $ in $(1)$. Same angle position, different representation, but this representation within the interval $0 \leq x\lt 2\pi$.

Finally, in the last problem, you list one solution as $x = - \pi/6$. Again this needs to be in your interval $0 \leq x \lt 2\pi$. So instead of $-\pi/6$, represent that angle as $2\pi - \pi/6 = 11\pi/6$.

Comment: can you show me a solution to this :) with the answers clear at the end?

Comment: $1)$ $x\in \{0, \pi/3, \pi, 5\pi/3\}$, $(2)$ $x\in \{\pi/2, 7\pi/6, 11\pi/6\}$

Comment: Your solutions to the equations are correct: $\tan x = 0, \cos x = 1/2$ for $(1)$ and for $(2)$L $\sin x = -1/2$ and $\sin x = 1$. You just needed to have your $x$ values being angles within the interval $0 \leq x \lt 2\pi$.

Comment: Does that help, now?

Comment: yes :D could you possibly show each step though? I want something to compare

Comment: You completed all the steps needed: you solved the equations just fine. All that had to be "fine-tuned" is representing the angles you found by their representations within the interval $0 \leq x \lt 2\pi$. I would just be rewriting what you wrote. Also, you might want to think about accepting some of the answers to your questions (you can only accept one answer per question, though.) At the very least, for the answers that are helpful, you should upvote them: there's no limit on how many answers you can upvote.

Comment: I did "clean up" your post, in terms of formatting, to make your ideas and work flow nicely. Include the updated solution sets for $(1)$ and $(2)$ that I've posted above in the comment, and you've got a nicely solved problem.

Comment: @amWhy I think he means a different way of solving this problems - if that's the case for the first problem you could notice that if $\tan x = 0$ this is true ($0=0$) or then do the following: $$2 \tan x \cos x = \tan x \iff 2 \cos x = 1 \iff \cos x = 1/2$$